# Choppy sound on MediaRecorder when playing video along side the recording

Tags: reactjs, video-recording, web-mediarecorder, mediadevices

I'm trying to build a website with ***React*** that let me record myself using `MediaRecorder` with another video running in the background, but when the other video volume is up the sound of the record is choppy and scrappy, when I turn the video volume down the sound of the record is good, at first I was thinking the problem happends when the sound of the other video is also recorded and disturbe the the actual record, but even when I'm using a microphone and headphones the problem seems to happend, I think its something in my code.

This is the function that init the recorder:

```
const initVideoStream = async () => {
    const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(async function (stream) {
      const options = {
        mimeType: 'audio/webm'

      }
      recorder.current = new MediaRecorder(stream, options)
      recorder.current.ondataavailable = e => {
        recordedChunks.current.push(e.data)
      }
      recorder.current.onstop = async e => {
        setisBlob(true)
        setVideoBlob(new Blob(recordedChunks.current, { 'type': 'video/mp4' }))
        const videoUrlObj = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(recordedChunks.current, { 'type': 'video/mp4' }))
        recorderRef.current.src = videoUrlObj
        recordedChunks.current = []
      }
      return stream
    }).catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
      setErrorMsg('Cannot find any camera,please check if your camera is connected and try again')
      setIsPopupOpen(true)
    });
    recordedChunks.current = []


    setStream(stream)
  }
```

I've tried to change the `mimeType` to `"video/mp4"` and that didn't help.

I've upload my project to netlidy so you can see the problem:
https://recorder-poc.netlify.app/

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that by default the MediaRecorder has echo cancellation that will make problems to my recording and i was needed to add this to my constraints:

```
{
    echoCancellation: false,
    autoGainControl: false,
    noiseSuppression: false
}
```